# fetching the value from map and addidng it to arguements of another method call

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

I have the method below in which I am fetching a map and storing it contents on another map as shown below ...

```
public void generatetrp(String p1,
            String p2, String p3,String p4) {            

Map<Integer, Integer> finalresult2 =   abcd.execute1(p1,
                p2, p3, p4,null, null, null, null);
    // now this map consists of key value pair and it will be the arguemts P5 AND P6 for next method call
    // map key will be arguement P5 and 
    // map Value will be arguement P6       
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : finalresult2.entrySet())
    {
       abc.generateabcRange(String p1,String p2, String p3, String p4,String p5, String p6) ;
```

below is the another method and this method is called from the previous method..

```
public void generateabcRange(String p1,
        String p2, String p3, String p4,
        String p5, String p6) {


    //method is running some buisness logic
}
```

Can you please advise how can I fetch the value from map one by one and inject the key and value to the arguements p5 and p6 at each iteration.

```
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice.